# How can I connect my LG env 2 cell phone to XP to explore it like an external drive?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, external-hard-drive

Sorry about the long descriptive title

So I got a new phone and I was wanting to transfer some of the stuff off of my old LG env 2 cell phone to my computer. I have the usb cable but I'm not sure how to be able to explore it like an external drive.